# Get Position of current Tab of my ViewPager in Listview's getView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager. 
Inside ViewPager, I have ListViews.

What I need is to know the number of the ViewPager tab's inside the getView in my listView.

Is it posible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get the current view pager item using bellow statement

mViewPager.getCurrentItem()

Comment: you have to send the viewpager reference in the list view adapter as a parameter